# Problems upgrading to Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4

Since I upgraded my iPhone to 5.1 I have been unable to use it with my current Xcode version 4.2 I then tried to download Xcode 4.3 but was told that I needed Mac OS version 10.7.3 or later. I'm currently on version 10.6.8. When I run software updates it does not offer me a later version. Then having checked out the Mac Store I can see OS X Lion 10.7.3 updates but how do I update my current OS from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to buy Mac OS X Lion from the App Store.

Comment: Apple usually doesn't give any other choice but to upgrade to the latest OS. At least it's not that expensive, and Xcode is free.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you hace to install from App Store for legar copy. It´s not expensive and useful!

Comment: Hi Guisante, please note you should post comments like these as "comments" and not "answers".